# Scalar slurpies?

Tags: raku, rakudo

As far as I (and the [docs](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#Slurpy_parameters)) know, slurpies can only be used with array or hash parameters.  However, I recently typo'ed the syntax and entered what looks like it would be the syntax for a scalar slurpy.  Much to my surprise, this didn't result in a syntax error.  After some experimentation, I determined that the following are all allowed:

```
sub f(*$a)  {}
sub g(**$a) {}
sub h(+$a)  {}
```

I couldn't, however see what (if anything) this syntax did.  So what's going on?  Is this an under-documented feature?  A bug that's causing invalid syntax not to throw an error?  Something else altogether?

Comment: Based on my reading of S06, it would have been possible to have a signature like `\(*$a, *@bcdef)` which would have been effectively identical to `\(*@ [$a, *@bcdef)`.  In many cases that might be identical to `\($a, *@bcdef)`. but not always due to the flattening nature of some of the slurpies (particularly single star).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So what's going on? Is this an under-documented feature? A bug that's causing invalid syntax not to throw an error? Something else altogether?

Its undocumented and broken behaviour. It was speculated it would have different behaviour. It's a filed bug. See [Slurpy scalar parameters](https://github.com/Raku/old-issue-tracker/issues/4609) (and duplicate https://github.com/Raku/old-issue-tracker/issues/5656) for further discussion.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  Between what and @user0721090601 said, I discovered that this behavior is (sort of) tested in Roast: https://github.com/Raku/roast/blob/master/S06-signature/slurpy-params.t#L145-L158